# Big O notation manipulation $\frac{1}{t^2} O(t^3)=\frac{1}{t^2} O(t)$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

I'd like to know why the following manipulation is right; I know the definition of big O, but in this case I don't know how to apply it.
$$\frac{1}{t^2} O(t^3)=\frac{1}{t^2} O(t)$$

EDIT: $t$ tends to zero.

Comment: What? $t^2=O(t^3)$ but $t^2\ne O(t)$ when $t$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Hello @Nightflight are you saying that the above equation doesn't make any sense?

Comment: Yes, @GennaroArguzzi. You do not gave any clue about $t$ goes to somewhere. Your question is generally not true.

Answer (score 1):

Just recalling the definition of the big O notation:

$f(x) = O(g(x)) \quad \text{when } x \rightarrow A \text{ iff} \quad \frac{|f(x)|}{|g(x)|} \leq C$, $x\rightarrow A$

Then if $f(x) = O(t^3) \implies |\frac{f(x)}{t^3}| \leq C$

Then $h(x) = \frac{1}{t^2}O(t^3)$ when $t\rightarrow 0$ iff

$$
\left|\frac{t^2 h(x)}{t^3}\right| \leq C, \quad 0<C
$$

Then, $|h(x)/t| \leq C$

and you are there.
Hope this helps.

Edit: Made it a little more clear, including $t \rightarrow 0$

Comment: Hello @pablich thank you for your answer; I'm using the definition with the limit of the ratio of the two function, when $t$ tends to zero.

Comment: I just edited my answer addressing that, I think it should work